# Only shows 10 rows?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

```
global $wpdb;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product_variation',
    'meta_key' => '_stock',
    'meta_value' => '0',
    'meta_compare' => '>'
);


$variationloop = new WP_Query( $args );
echo  $wpdb->num_rows . 'Rows Found</br>';

while ( $variationloop->have_posts() ) :
    $variationloop->the_post();
    echo '<br /><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a>';
endwhile;
```

The num_rows indicates 499 rows. But i only get 10 rows displayed. Why?

Comment: [WP_Query documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters). Search the page for `posts_per_page`. It doesn't mention a default value but there probably is one somewhere.

Comment: pass posts_per_page in your $args

Answer (score 0):

Add a new argument:

```
'posts_per_page' => '-1'
```

Other questions you may have about [$wpdb](http://wpdb.webstuffdepot.com/) may be answered here.